# Angular Material warnings shown when unit testing component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, jestjs

I am currently writing some units test for some Angular components that make use of [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components). The issue I am having now is I keep getting the following warnings when running the unit tests.

```
console.warn node_modules\@angular\material\bundles\material.umd.js:183
Current document does not have a doctype. This may cause some Angular Material components not to behave as expected.

console.warn node_modules\@angular\material\bundles\material.umd.js:196
Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.ang
ular.io/guide/theming

console.warn node_modules\@angular\material\bundles\material.umd.js:3327
Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may not work correctly.
```

Is it normal to see these warnings? Any ideas on how to suppress these warnings as I don't see them really relevant to unit testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a hack of suppressing the warnings. In Jest configuration, there's an option to set up script files that can configure Jest testing framework.

```
"jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setup.ts",
  }
```

See [setupTestFrameworkScriptFile](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string) option from Jest API doc

> The path to a module that runs some code to configure or set up the
>   testing framework before each test. Since setupFiles executes before
>   the test framework is installed in the environment, this script file
>   presents you the opportunity of running some code immediately after
>   the test framework has been installed in the environment.

Then in `setup.ts`, we do the following to suppress all warnings.

```
console.warn = function() {};
```

Probably not the most ideal way, but did do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve this by adding the following line to the files array in karma.config.js

```
 files: [
            {pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false},
            {
                pattern: './node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css',
                included: true,
                watched: true
            }
        ],
```